# Flink timestamps in events & stream records

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

looking at documentation and books of Flink I have doubt about the timestamps: if a stream is set in event-time mode and this means the timestamps have the time of the source before getting into Flink (even before going through a messaging queue, which could be Kafka), why Flink attaches timestamps to records as metadata?
slide 3 having the different types of timestamps according to what they account for:
https://www.slideshare.net/dataArtisans/apache-flink-training-time-and-watermarks

If the timestamp is coming inside of the event why to pass that value to a metadata of the record? also what would exactly be the difference between the event and the recod?

Comment: Those training slides are quite out of date. You'll find more up-to-date content at http://training.ververica.com.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamps don't always come from inside of the events. For example, the Flink Kafka consumer copies the timestamps in the Kafka metadata to the Flink metadata. (You can supply a timestamp assigner if you wish to overwrite these timestamps.)

These timestamps carried in the stream record metadata are used internally in various ways:

- the built-in event-time window assigners use these timestamps to assign events to windows
- CEP uses these timestamps to sort the stream into event time order
- Flink SQL can also use these timestamps for sorting, windowing, etc.

Comment: Could you note some links with example of Kafka timestamps and how to extract them to the metadata of Flink events? I don't get if the time information is passed manually from one field to Flink metadata or is there some function to do that... Also if I define the Timestamps as event Time and then I attach the timestamps after receiving the events from for example Kafka what would be the problems or errors arisen?

Comment: I rewrote my answer to clarify what's going on. You don't need to extract the timestamps from the metadata -- this happens automatically. See the docs for more info. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#watermark-strategies-and-the-kafka-connector